How to identify GA4 key events in Google BigQuery (to correctly calculate engaged sessions)?
I'm exporting GA4 event data to Google BigQuery to later analyze the data.
In the GA4 property settings, you can mark specific events as "key events", which you can later use to optimize you GAds campaigns and Google uses them to identify if a session is engaged.

An engaged session is a session that lasts longer than 10 seconds, has a key events, or has at least 2 pageviews or screenviews.
There is a session_engaged event parameter in BigQuery (which is set by GA4, but not correlates to the key events), and I can also identify the time and page-/screenview events, but how do I find/identify those marked key events in Google BigQuery?
I woud expect them to be flagged within the event_params.

as is_conversion_event or something like that, but I can't find anything.
I can't write down all key event names and compare them manually, as I work with multiple propertys and different key events, so that's not an option.
If I can't identify the key events, is there any other way to calculate the "correct" number of engaged sessions which includes the key event correlation?

Key events are not directly available in BigQuery Export. However, if your goal is to count engaged sessions, you can query this field directly. Check out this query:
  select
    count(distinct case when (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'session_engaged') = '1' then concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id')) end) as engaged_sessions
    from
    `table-id`


Yes I know that, that's what I mentioned above. It sadly doesn't include sessions that are engaged because there happened a key event
